# Access a server running in one vm of an instance group from other vms(of same MIG) with a dns name

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-dns, gce-instance-group, google-cloud-internal-load-balancer

Created a managed instance group(MIG) with 3 vms
Created an internal load balancer to access this group via DNS [communicating via port 443]
Created DNS entries

There is a jetty server running on port 5000 in one of these VMs which I'd like to connect to from the application running in other VMs via a DNS

One way of achieving that is to use VMs internal DNS like {$vm_name}{$region_name}{$project_id}.internal but i need to create this DNS at runtime, but looking for a dedicated DNS to directly connecting to the VM running a standalone jetty server on port 5000

Anyone knows another way to achieve this, please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: List the Compute Engine instances. Then “describe” each instance. One of the JSON keys is the DNS name.

Comment: @JohnHanley could you please help me with the gcloud command as when I describe an instance no zonal dns(ending with .internal) comes up.

Comment: And, is it possible to get the same FQDN (Zonal dns) via google compute engine api?

Comment: Do you see `name` in the output? With that, you can construct the FQDN. I am not sure about the API to get the FQDN - I have not checked. The Compute Engine [metadata server](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/metadata/overview) also has this information.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [Zonal DNS](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/networking/zonal-dns).

If you are using a zonal MIG, create a zonal DNS record in your VPC network that points to the VM's internal IP address. Use this DNS name from other VMs in the same zone to access the server. This is only accessible within the same zone, not across multiple zones.

See also this [document](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/networking/using-internal-dns) for more info.

Comment: Zonal DNS is same as compute vm internal dns name (mentioned in the question)  {$vm_name}{$region_name}{$project_id}.internal ?? And how can i send a http request for this DNS as i get `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Host name may not be null` exception